# Does logback's shutdownHook unregister the jmxConfigurator

Tags: jmx, logback

I am making use of the `<jmxConfigurator/>` element in logback; The jmxConfigurator states the following:

```
Thus, unless your application is a standalone Java application, you **MUST** unregister the JMXConfigurator instance from the JVM's Mbeans server.
```

The logback documentation also mentions a `<shutdownHook/>` configuration element which according to the documentation does the following:

```
Installing a JVM shutdown hook is a convenient way for shutting down logback and releasing associated resources.
```

Does including the `<shutdownHook/>` element take care of unregistering the `<jmxConfigurator/>`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, it does. Here is a proof from the debugger:
[image]

However, there are a few restrictions:

1. `<shutdownHook/>` is available only as of version 1.1.3
2. although [the documentation says](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html#shutdownHook) that plain `<shutdownHook/>` is enough, you have to specify the `class` property:
   `<shutdownHook class="ch.qos.logback.core.hook.DelayingShutdownHook"/>`
   otherwise logback complains with:

   ```
   ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.joran.action.ShutdownHookAction - Missing class name for shutdown hook. Near [shutdownHook] line 16
   ```

To make sure that the JMXConfigurator gets stopped enable debug mode on the logback configuration:

```
<configuration debug="true">
   ...
</configuration>
```

Then at the end of your logs you'll see:

```
INFO in ch.qos.logback.core.hook.DelayingShutdownHook@1a246fc6 - Logback context being closed via shutdown hook
INFO in ch.qos.logback.classic.jmx.JMXConfigurator(default) - onReset() method called JMXActivator [ch.qos.logback.classic:Name=default,Type=ch.qos.logback.classic.jmx.JMXConfigurator]
```